# Can't get PHP include keyword to work

Tags: php, html

I'm learning PHP and have just discovered how handy the include keyword is, and have started using it on one of the sites I built for the company I work for.

Now the site I'm applying this to uses Perch CMS for sections of the website, and the Perch blog extension.

I've got the inlclude's working on all files located in the root directory, but one of the files is a Perch CMS blog template, that's located a couple of subdirectories in and the PHP include will not work in this file.

The directory of the files I'm trying to include are **../inc/**.

The directory of the Perch blog template with the include that *doesn't work* is **../perch/templates/blog/**.

**[EDIT]** Sorry I also forgot to mention something which might be important, the file I'm using this include in is used by Perch CMS as a template for how to display the blog posts, it's a regular .html file (although I have a line in my .htaccess file that allows php to be executed in .html files).**[/EDIT]**

I'm using wamp and in my **www** directory I have multiple folders each acting as a root directory for different projects, this is set up and working using **projectName.localhost** as the address.
For example one of them is called **f3racing** and the address is **f3racing.localhost** and the folder structure is **wamp/www/f3racing/**.

In all the other files (located in the root directory) this works:

```
<?php include("inc/header.php"); ?>
```

I have tried these:

```
<?php include("../../../inc/header.php"); ?>

<?php include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/inc/header.php"); ?>

<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/inc/header.php"); ?>

<?php include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/f3racing/inc/header.php"); ?>

<?php
     include(
       $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
       $path .= "/inc/header.php";
       include_once($path);
     );
?>
```

I'm completely stumped as to what to do nest to get this working, should one of these work under normal circumstances? What I mean by that is if I *wasn't* using Perch CMS would these work?

Comment: When you say "doesn't work", what error are you getting?

Comment: @NickR why would OP want to use an absolute path?

Comment: @danrob I'm not getting the file I'm trying to include, in this case it's the header code for the site. -Sorry, I'm not getting any error message, just simply lack of include file.

Comment: use require instead of include, it will give more information on failure

Comment: I suggest also to display all errors : adding the following at the top of your php script:  `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors', 'On');`.
You can use magic constant like `__DIR__` and `__FILE__` to know what the current absolute path and use it instead of DOCUMENT_ROOT which is not always present.

Comment: I've tried replacing include with require (is that the correct syntax? <?php require("inc/header.php"); ?> I haven't really used require before) and still nothing, which leads me to believe that it's the fact its being used as a template by the CMS that's the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `../` wrong.

`../` means "go up one directory".

If your file is in `/usr/var/www/path/` then doing `include('../anotherfile.php')` in that file will look for the file `/usr/var/www/anotherfile.php` (notice we've gone up a directory).

Your file is in `/usr/var/www/perch/templates/blog/` and you want to reference a file in `/usr/var/www/inc/`. So you need to "go back" 3 folders (so you're in the `www` folder) and then reference the `inc` directory and then the file.

Your include should look like this:

```
include('../../../inc/header.php');
```

Try that, that should work.

Edit: I don't know wamp very well but I guess that you could swap the `/usr/var/www` bit in my examples above for something like `c:/Program Files/WAMP/www` or whatever the directory path is. Its all the same theory.

Comment: Sorry to cause confusion, but I do understand how to use ../ and have tried using ../ as many directories as I need to go up and this still doesn't work.

Comment: `../` just means "go up one directory". So if you're in `c:/Users/me` then `../` refers to `c:/Users`. It's as simple as that. If you're sure you've tried that and its not working then there's something else not right. That should definitely work.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see what's wrong with:

```
<?php include("../../../inc/header.php"); ?>
```

From what I can gather by your description, you have a file:

`root/inc/header.php`

and another file:

`root/perch/templates/blog/some_file.php`

Which contains the above `include`.

I tested this by having `header.php` contain `echo "header.php";` then loaded `some_file.php`.

Comment: Right, that's what I'm starting to suspect, that it's the way the CMS is using the file containing the include that's the problem. I've posted on the CMS support forum to see if they can shed some light on it.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it's the way Perch CMS deals with template files that's causing the problem. Thanks for all your suggestions, answers and advice there was no way of you guys knowing this was the problem.

**[EDIT]**

I'll elaborate just in case anyone else has the same issue in the future:

I was trying to add php into the perch template file, located in *perch/templates/blog/post.html* in a standard install, turns out that file will not run any PHP inside it, the code needs to go into the perch file *blog/post.php* and the post.html file edited accordingly.

**[/EDIT]**

Once again, much appreciated.